# Code to Generate Sequential Code with a Prefix

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small userform with 1 combobox, 2 textbox and 1 command button. Image is attached.[image]

Also the image of worksheet is attached below.
[image]

Upon Initialization of Userform, combobox is populated with account heads listed in Table1.

Selection of item from combobox will populate the textbox with Account Code listed in Table1.

Group Head textbox will be entered manually.

Below is my code...

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, rng As Range, cmb As ComboBox
Dim accountcode As String, rng1 As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
Set rng = tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
Set rng1 = tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange


Me.TextBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(rng, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ComboBox1.Value, rng1, 0))


End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, row As ListRow

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table2")
Set row = tbl.ListRows.Add

prefix = Me.TextBox1.Value & "-"

Dim NextNum As Long
Dim LastRow As Long, lRow As Long
Dim myArr() As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
'Find Last Row in Group Head Code Column
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row

ReDim myArr(1 To LastRow)
' read all cells contents and convert them to array of numbers
For lRow = 5 To LastRow
    If Mid(.Cells(lRow, 5), 4) <> "" Then
        myArr(lRow) = CLng(Mid(.Cells(lRow, 5), 4))
    End If
Next lRow

' find maximum value in array
NextNum = WorksheetFunction.Max(myArr)

End With
row.Range(1, 1).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
row.Range(1, 2).Value = prefix & NextNum + 1
row.Range(1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, rng As Range, cmb As ComboBox

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
Set rng = tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
Set cmb = Me.ComboBox1

For Each rng In rng
cmb.AddItem rng.Value
Next rng

End Sub
```

The command button reads the value in Table 2, COlumn and 2, Generate the serial number and post the values in the Table.

What i want with the command button is, if i select any other head from the combobox, the code should read the value associated with that prefix and then generate the next serial number. Currently it is not reading the prefix.

Kindly advise what changes need to be made in my command button code to achieve this.

Thanks
Salman

Comment: I appreciate that you've expanded on your previous post, but it's still not clear what you're asking. I think you're saying that you want to detect if the current `ComboBox` text is different from that which was previously held in the `ComboBox` since the last time the user clicked the `CommandButton`; if so, then generate a new code based on the current `ComboBox` text and a number incremented by one from the last code with the same prefix. Is that correct?

Comment: Somehow you are correct. I illustrate with a small example. e.g. If i made 2 entries with prefix AT, the code generates the serial number in sequence. But if i change the prefix to ET, it should generate the serial number from the start not from 2. Hope it will be clear now...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're experiencing is that you're trying to use `Sheet1` as both the output display and data storage system. Often this isn't a problem, but in your case, it's causing you to have to search `Table2` each time an entry is made.

You'd be better off using a module-level variable in VBA to keep track of the incrementing number for each code. There's also no need to look up `Table 1` each time a selection is made. You could either store the codes in another module-level variable or exploit the ability for `ComboBoxes` to have more than one column. In the sample below I've gone for the latter because it's easy to read the `ListObject` straight into the combo box `List` property - if you want to go the same route, then you'd need to change the combo box `ColumnCount` property to `2` and, if you want the codes to be invisible, change the `ColumnWidths` property to something like `0 pt;130 pt`.

Your code, then, could look something like the below:

```
Option Explicit
Private mNextInc() As Long

Private Function IndexOf(val As String, arr As Variant) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    'Get array index of lookup item
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 1) = val Then
            IndexOf = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Me.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim v As Variant

    With Me.ComboBox1
        'Create the output array
        v = Array(.Text, _
                  .Value & "-" & mNextInc(.ListIndex), _
                  Me.TextBox2.Text)

        'Write new row to table
        Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") _
                 .ListObjects("Table2")
        tbl.Range.Activate
        If tbl.InsertRowRange Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Offset(tbl.ListRows.Count + 1)
        Else
            Set rng = tbl.InsertRowRange
        End If
        rng.Value = v

        'Increment the digit of code
        mNextInc(.ListIndex) = mNextInc(.ListIndex) + 1
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim lRow As ListRow
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim inc As Long
    Dim i As Long

    'Populate the combobox
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") _
              .ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange
    Me.ComboBox1.List = rng.Value

    'Set the increment values to 1
    ReDim mNextInc(rng.Rows.Count - 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(mNextInc)
        mNextInc(i) = 1
    Next

    'Find current max value for each group head code
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") _
              .ListObjects("Table2")
    For Each lRow In tbl.ListRows
        With lRow.Range
            i = IndexOf(.Cells(1), rng.Value)
            inc = CLng(Mid(.Cells(2), 4, Len(.Cells(2)) - 3)) + 1
        End With
        If inc > mNextInc(i) Then mNextInc(i) = inc
    Next

    'Set the combo box to first item
    Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: runtime error 5 at line  " inc = CLng(Mid(.Cells(2), 4, Len(.Cells(2)) - 3)) + 1
"

Comment: That means the data in column 2 of Table2 isn't as you've shown in your example. Most likely there's an empty cell or one with fewer than 4 characters, or the number doesn't start at the 4th character in the string. You'll have to check that yourself, I'm afraid.